# How do add a timer that resets after each level is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to add a restarting timer to my simon game. I know `setInterval()` and `SetTimeout` but I can't figure out how to have the timer reset for each level if the level is passed within the first 10 seconds. Do I need an if/else to work and concatenate it to level or userClickPattern? I dont know, I tried it all.
Goal:
Have a 10 second timer that starts .click and if the pattern is completed to move to the next sequence if it is not completed then alert("... ) and restart the game. The timer function is at the bottom. Please help me!!!

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];

var gamePattern = [];
var userClickedPattern = [];

var started = false;
var level = 0;

$(document).keypress(function() {
  if (!started) {
    $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
    nextSequence();
    started = true;
  }
});

$(".btn").click(function() {

  var userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);

  playSound(userChosenColour);
  animatePress(userChosenColour);

  checkAnswer(userClickedPattern.length - 1);

});

function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {

  if (gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {

    console.log("success");

    if (userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        nextSequence();
      }, 1000);
    }

  } else {

    console.log("wrong");

    playSound("wrong");

    $("body").addClass("game-over");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("body").removeClass("game-over");
    }, 200);

    $("#level-title").text("Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart");


    startOver();
  }

}

function nextSequence() {

  userClickedPattern = [];
  level++;
  $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);


  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);

  $("#" + randomChosenColour).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
  playSound(randomChosenColour);

}

function playSound(name) {
  var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + name + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
}

function animatePress(currentColor) {
  $("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#" + currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
  }, 100);
}

function startOver() {
  level = 0;
  gamePattern = [];
  started = false;
}

function timer() {

  alert("Out Of Time Better Luck Next time");
  playSound("wrong");

  $("#level-title").text("Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart");
  startOver();
}
```

Comment: global (at your module level) `var  gameTimer = null;` then `gameTimer = setTimeout... ` and on success `clearTimeout(gameTimer)`

Comment: okay, so the timer now alerts and makes the sound and restarts the game, however it only does it the first 9ish seconds and doesnt restart the timer for each level. I added an if/else statement so that it restarts but no budge.

Comment: setTimeout(function (Gametimer) {
if (console.log()==="success") {
  clearTimeout(timer);
}
else {

       console.log("wrong");
       playSound("wrong");
       alert("Out Of Time Better Luck Next time");
}

     $("#level-title").text("Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart");
     startOver();

}, 9000);   var gameTimer=null;

Comment: @freedomn-m...  Sorry I forgot to add your tag so you could see my follow up question.. also this is first real game so I am loss! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a timer is easy with `setInterval`, which, unlike `setTimeout`, will continue to execute the handler function with the specified delay until the interval is cleared.

If you wanted the value globally, you could do:

```js
let seconds = 0
let timerInterval

function startTimer() {
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => seconds++, 1000)
}

function resetTimer() {
  seconds = 0
  clearInterval(timerInterval)
}
```